# Damage on Tesla Coil Secondary - is it ok?

Tags: transformer, tesla-coil, secondary-winding

I am building a small tesla coil (the OneTesla TinyTesla) and my secondary coil has some small damage. Is this damage tolerable as long as the wires still have continuity, or does it need to be a perfect coil? I have already varnished the coil and put some packing tape on it, and would not like to remove it unless I really have to.

[image: Image showing some damage to the secondary coil]
[image: Image showing some damage to the secondary coil]

Comment: Is the coil open? If not, does the isolation varnish hold up to the voltage or does it jump to neighboring windings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go ahead and build, tune and operate the coil. Don't let perfection be the enemy of the 'good enough'. This will not stop the coil working. It won't even stop it working well.

This level of damage will reduce the maximum voltage that the coil can sustain before it flashes over or does other nasty thing, but only by a very small margin. You will learn plenty setting up the coil to work.

Operate the secondary with the damaged end of the coil at the groundy end, if only one end is damaged. This will reduce the tendency for it to misbehave. If you want to operate it with the damage at the high voltage end, you can reduce the voltage gradient around the damage by mounting the toroid closer than you normally would.

If the coating allows, you could unwind the dozen or so damaged turns, to get a clean end to the secondary.

If you want to show the coil, then of course you'll want to build a perfect secondary. That can wait until you've learnt what you can from this one. With all due respect, that secondary is not really show quality anyway, with the uneven coating evident in the photos.

Comment: Thank you very much; this is an SSTC coil that my friend and I built a while ago, but it never worked, and I'm trying to narrow down my problems. From what you said here, I don't think it will be a problem as the toroid goes right on top, so there's only about 3mil of space between. Will there be any problem with air bubbles under the tape if there are any?

Comment: @Klumpy7 not sure why you have tape there. Even if it's applied very evenly, there will be inevitable inhomogenities and bubbles that will confound whatever purpose there was (presumably insulation?) in putting it on in the first place. Arc to/from secondary is usually prevented by having it perfectly even. An insulation layer does little to stop 100's kV punching through. If there is to be an insulation layer, then an even coat of varnish or epoxy (or several) is the way to go. Clear tape is just unnecessary and insufficient. Don't worry about the bubbles, any more than the tape itself.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll take the tape off and add another several layers of varnish. The instructions I had said to add packing tape if I wanted for extra insulation, but this sounds better.

Comment: @Klumpy7 Just use it as it is. Don't worry about taking the tape off, or adding extra insulation. The tape isn't really that important, or any extra insulation. It's just making it look messy. Get on with the rest of the build. Polish your system once it's making big sparks, not before.

Comment: @Klumpy7 The main purpose of extra insulation over the secondary is mechanical protection, so you can dismantle, transport, drop, the secondary without damaging the copper. With a big spark gap coil with plenty of power, a perfect secondary is needed to get the very longest sparks out of it. With a small TC, especially a SSTC type like the tiny Tesla, the secondary is the least of your problems, and getting enough power through the primary is the hard bit.